# Mouse doesn't work

Tags: drivers, mouse, zorin

I a have a problem. The mouse led is working, put the mouse pointer doesn't move and system doesn't respond to mousecliks. Touchpad works fine. And on Windows it works just fine.

I tried to reinstall the xorg packages, but that didn't help. I have ZorinOS 12.

`lsusb` can see it, too. It is a Trust usb mouse.

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e360 Atheros Communications, Inc. 

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:1158 Syntek 

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Don't have old mouse to test with.

Comment: What (hardware) mouse? Did you try to plug some cheap USB mouse? What Xorg configuration?

Comment: The overwhelming majority of the usb mouses use the same usb protocol, thus they work with the same driver. However, to see the problem more clearly, if you have some old mouse in the desk, I suggest to try that, too.

Comment: `lsusb` output, please. In the question, not in a comment. As already suggested, try a different USB mouse. And also try a more mainstream distribution, like an Ubuntu Live CD, and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: First step: Run `evtest` (as root), select mouse device, see if it produces move/click events if you move the mouse/click buttons. If not, check `dmesg` for anything related to that device, and update question with this information. If it does, check `Xorg.log` for anything related to that device, update question.